# Sports Connect Wall

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall, sports

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #42: Wordless Connecting Walls](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7045/fortnightly-topic-challenge-42-wordless-connecting-walls)</sup>

---

The sports here can be grouped into four groups.

[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]

#### To solve the puzzle

**With two of the four groups, form the following sport.**

[image]

**While with the two remaining groups, form the following sport.**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the sports from top to bottom:

> Boxing, Kung Fu, Go, Ice Hockey, Inline speed skating, Auto Racing, Surfing, Badminton, Rock Climbing, Sailing, Pool, F1, Chess, Baseball, Basket Ball, Rallying

Groups.

1.

> Non-team sports (Chess, Inline Speed skating, Rock Climbing, Go)

2. 

> Point based (Basketball, Kung fu, Boxing, Surfing)

3. 

> Uses Vehicles (F1, Rallying, Auto Racing, Sailing)

4. 

> Uses a stick (Badminton, Ice Hockey, Pool, Baseball)

And so:

> First two groups are related to Judo.

> Second two are related to Dragon Boating.

Comment: Can I please get confirmation on whether this is right or not?

Comment: You have found another really convenient way to group the sports. Category 3 is exactly the one I planned and all other three categories vary from mine. It's no big deal as you still managed to correctly create Judo and Dragon Boating, so congrats! Thick and +1 ;) PS : it's Bandy and not Ice Hockey ;)